# Inserting arrays in Elasticsearch via PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I have a case much like this one:

Example DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([  # schema
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("email", ArrayType(StringType()), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"id": "id1"},
                            {"id": "id2", "email": None},
                            {"id": "id3","email": ["email1@gmail.com"]},
                            {"id": "id4", "email": ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"]}],
                           schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
+---+------------------------------------+
|id |email                               |
+---+------------------------------------+
|id1|null                                |
|id2|null                                |
|id3|[email1@gmail.com]                  |
|id4|[email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com]|
+---+------------------------------------+
```

I want to insert this data into Elasticsearch, so as far as I researched, I have to transform into the indexing format:

```
def parseTest(r):
    if r['email'] is None:
        return r['id'],{"id":r['id']}
    else:
        return r['id'],{"id":r['id'],"email":r['email']}
df2 = df.rdd.map(lambda row: parseTest(row))
df2.top(4)
[('id4', {'email': ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'], 'id': 'id4'}),
 ('id3', {'email': ['email1@gmail.com'], 'id': 'id3'}),
 ('id2', {'id': 'id2'}),
 ('id1', {'id': 'id1'})]
```

Then I try to insert:

```
es_conf = {"es.nodes" : "node1.com,node2.com",
           "es.resource": "index/type"}
df2.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-', 
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf=es_conf)
```

And I get this:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Data of type java.util.ArrayList
>   cannot be used

```
Spark v 2.1.0
ES v 2.4.4
```

Without the `email` field it works fine, I found some proposed solution using the `es.output.json: true` and `json.dumps`, but it appeared to be for version 5, so I tried in another cluster I have with ES v5

```
df3 = df2.map(json.dumps)
df3.top(4)
['["id4", {"email": ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"], "id": "id4"}]',
 '["id3", {"email": ["email1@gmail.com"], "id": "id3"}]',
 '["id2", {"id": "id2"}]',
 '["id1", {"id": "id1"}]']
es_conf2 = {"es.nodes" : "anothernode1.com,anothernode2.com",
           "es.output.json": "true",
           "es.resource": "index/type"}
df3.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-', 
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf=es_conf2)
```

Then I get:

> RDD element of type java.lang.String cannot be used

```
Spark v 2.1.0
ES v 5.2.0
```

feelsbadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do the same job, by using the `write` method of a dataframe object.

So, following the first section:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([  # schema
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("email", ArrayType(StringType()), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"id": "id1"},
                            {"id": "id2", "email": None},
                            {"id": "id3","email": ["email1@gmail.com"]},
                            {"id": "id4", "email": ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"]}],
                           schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
+---+------------------------------------+
|id |email                               |
+---+------------------------------------+
|id1|null                                |
|id2|null                                |
|id3|[email1@gmail.com]                  |
|id4|[email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com]|
+---+------------------------------------+
```

You just need to:

```
df.write\
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
    .option("es.nodes","node1.com,node2.com")\
    .option("es.resource","index/type")\
    .option("es.mapping.id", "id")\
    .save()
```

No need to transform into a RDD or modify in any manner.